# Create a dictionary from two lists in python matching the number of letters in each word

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists

```
a= ['and', 'people', 'them', 'become', 'treat', 'is', 'they', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you', 'what']
b= [3, 6, 4, 6, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

I need a dictionary where the keys are the numbers in `b` and values are the words in `a`. However, the keys' values must be unique. So, the output is like this:

```
c= {2 : 'is', 3 : ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'], 5 : 'treat', 6 : 'become'}
```

I've tried this:

```
mydict = {key:value for key, value in zip(b, a)}
print (mydict)
```

This is the output:

```
{2: 'is', 3: 'and', 4: 'them', 5: 'treat', 6: 'become'}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to *always* use a list as the value? Then you can just use `mydict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` or a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. Otherwise you have three cases: key not present, key present with string value, key present with list value.

Comment: What is the output that you need?

Comment: I need this output: c= {2 : 'is', 3 : ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'], 5 : 'treat', 6 : 'become'}

Comment: @DanielTiezzi again, why not `5: ['treat']`?

Comment: So, words of the same length in a list of values assigned to the matched keys

Comment: I can't import anything to run this

Comment: What about word 'people'? Should it be it the output?

Comment: jonrshape. Sorry, you right.

Comment: c= {2 : ['is'], 3 : ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'], 5 : ['treat'], 6 : ['become']}
this would be the output

Comment: Yes, Ilja. You got it. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You may use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) class, which behaves as `dict` but can have default start values for missing keys. Try it in such a way:

```
    >>> a= ['and', 'people', 'them', 'become', 'treat', 'is', 'they', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you', 'what']
    >>> from collections import defaultdict
    >>> c=defaultdict(list)
    >>> for x in a: c[len(x)].append(x)
    >>> print(c)
    defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: ['is'], 3: ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'], 5: ['treat'], 6: ['people', 'become']})
```

Then you may use it like usual `dict`:

```
    >>> for k,v in c.items():
    >>>        print(k, ' : ', v)

    2  :  ['is']
    3  :  ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you']
    4  :  ['them', 'they', 'what']
    5  :  ['treat']
    6  :  ['people', 'become']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict={}
for i in xrange(len(b)):
    if b[i] not in dict:
        dict[b[i]]=[a[i]]
    else:
        dict[b[i]].append(a[i])
print dict
```

you will get the result what you need.

```
{2: ['is'], 3: ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'],5: ['treat'], 6: ['people', 'become']}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I noted in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029423/create-a-dictionary-from-two-lists-in-python-matching-the-number-of-letters-in-e#comment59708806_36029423), this means dealing with three cases:

1. Key not yet present
2. Key present, value is string
3. Key present, value is list

To do precisely what you want, therefore:

```
mydict = {}
for key, value in zip(map(len, a), a):
    # 1. 
    if key not in mydict: 
        mydict[key] = value
    # 2. 
    elif isinstance(mydict[key], str):
        mydict[key] = [mydict[key], value]
    # 3. 
    else:
        mydict[key].append(value)
```

Note the use of `map` and `len` to get the lengths on the fly.

However, as you can see, this is pretty complex, and now you have a dictionary with heterogeneous value types, which further complicates additional processing. Instead, I would recommend always using a list as the value, even for only a single string:

```
mydict = {}
for key, value in zip(map(len, a), a):
    if key not in mydict:
        mydict[key] = []
    mydict[key].append(value)
```

This is clearly neater and will probably simplify any additional steps you have. You can simplify this code further with the [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method or a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object, which is designed for this kind of thing.